# How to increase the open files user limit in boxfuse?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ulimit, sysctl, cloudcaptain

I'm receiving a "TooManyOpenFiles" exception. I already added a custom `src/main/resources/sysctl.conf`:

```
fs.file-max = 64000
```

But `UnixOperatingSystemMXBean#getMaxFileDescriptorCount()` returns still `4096`

I guess I'd also have to set the user limit - is there a way to do it in boxfuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxfuse Client 1.26.7.1312 and up now **automatically adjust the user limits to match the kernel limits**. See https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/releasenotes#1.26.7.1312 and https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/payloads/springboot#sysctl

Simply upgrade with `boxfuse -u` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I need to do what the other answer suggests, which is, update the ulimits. is that possible. can we increase the `limits` or do you know what the value is? We are hitting an issue on `Prod` that is basically looking like a lack of FD or some limits that prevents additional sockets from being created even though the instance is not being utilized (slow connections)

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the ulimit configuration too.

```
# vim /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Change or add the lines

```
*   hard    nofile  1048576
*   soft    nofile  1048576
```

Instead of using an *, you can put a specific username or a group prefixed with @ (@group)

Then you will have to reboot the system to apply the changes (or use the ulimit command)